# How to display data in string occuring in column but not in the same string

Tags: sql

So I want to find two words occurring in the column but not in the same string.
I tried using

```
Select * 
FROM TWEETS
WHERE TWEET LIKE '%ZELDA%
AND TWEET NOT LIKE '%GAME%';
```

But in cannot get a solution.

EDIT:

I am trying to query based on the filter 'ZELDA' and 'LEGEND' bot being in the Tweet.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) the tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Don't add a second `where` keyword, it is only required once in SQL. `Select * FROM TWEETS WHERE TWEET LIKE '%ZELDA% AND TWEET NOT LIKE '%GAME%';` Read the DB driver's error log if a statement didn't work as intended. Also check your DB manual about fulltext search and wildcards, not all DB software works the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like

```
SELECT   *
FROM    TWEETS
WHERE   (TWEET LIKE '%ZELDA%' AND TWEET NOT LIKE '%GAME%') OR
        (TWEET LIKE '%GAME%' AND TWEET NOT LIKE '%ZELDA%');
```

This way you will select all rows where the column `TWEET` contains the word 'ZELDA' and not the word 'GAME' or vice-versa.